# Docker able to RUN shell commands targeting the AWS CLI

Tags: docker, aws-cli

I am writing a `Dockerfile` for a Docker image which is parameterized with `aws` access key secrets (I am aware that best practice is to pass any and all secrets as environment variables at run time, but I am merely experimenting and not building something I expect to run in production).

However, when I run `docker build`, the build process unexpectedly fails.

The command I am running is:

```
docker build -t foobar . --build-arg aws_access_key_id=SOMETHING --build-arg aws_secret_access_key=SOMETHING_ELSE
```

The salient part of the `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.6

# set the working directory
RUN ["mkdir", "app"]
WORKDIR "app"

# install environment dependencies
COPY "requirements.txt" .

# install code dependencies
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]

# provision
ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key
RUN ["sh", "-c", "\"aws configure set aws_access_key_id $aws_access_key_id\""]
RUN ["sh", "-c", "\"aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $aws_secret_access_key\""]
```

The error messsage I recieve is:

```
sh: 1: aws configure set aws_access_key_id ******************MQ: not found
The command 'sh -c "aws configure set aws_access_key_id $aws_access_key_id"' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Essentially `sh` is saying that it isn't aware of any `aws` command at build time. However, I clearly indicate that `awscli` is a dependency in `requirements.txt`, which gets installed earlier (provided here for the sake of completeness; this is a one-line file):

```
awscli
```

These `sh` commands work on my local machine. They also work when I comment out these last two `sh` commands out of the image, build the image, shell in via `docker exec -it <pid> /bin/bash`, and execute them there.

Therefore my question is: why are these command are failing at build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your run command to the following:

```
RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id $aws_access_key_id
RUN aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $aws_secret_access_key
```

Reason:

The way you have it it's treating "`aws configure set aws_access_key_id $aws_access_key_id`" as the actual command instead of "`aws`" as the command.

Basically you're adding double quotes and resulting in this:

```
$ sh -c "\"echo foo\""
sh: echo foo: command not found
```

You can remove the escaped quotes in your example and it'll work.

Comment: What does it mean that the entire string, and not just the `aws` call, is treated as the command? Just trying to better understand what I'm still not quite seeing. Also, I thought that the malformed `RUN` command would result in an error code, and that the error code would cancel the entire `build`; how come this didn't happen?

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur because you have it quotes. Remove the escaped quotes in your example and it should work

Comment: I find this behavior very surprising to be honest. I'd expect the substrings in the list to be concatenated, e.g. `" ".join(...)` , before getting passed to an OS call. Your solution implies that in every case _except_ for the last, the double quote marker (`"`) is removed, which seems odd to me.

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur docker under the hood is using busybox, so it's actualy executing `"exec", "bb", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo foo"`. Busybox is doing the magic of parsing it correctly

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur The very low-level exec APIs take a list of strings, so the JSONish list syntax explicitly passes that list of strings; they don't get joined and then re-split.